# C - repeated printf() with %s and char *

Tags: c, printf

```
char * src_addr;
char * dst_addr;

src_addr = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src);
printf("src: %s\n", src_addr);

dst_addr = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst);
printf("dst: %s\n", dst_addr);

printf("src: %s\n", src_addr);
```

This will output the dst_addr in the third printf statement. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation: inet_ntoa() returns the dots-and-numbers string in a static buffer that is overwritten with each call to the function.

So, in your case the second call to inet_ntoa gives you a new string but in the same buffer, so dst_addr points to the same as src_addr, which now both point to the new destination string.

Comment: Well, that explains it. I was so focused on the printf behavior I failed to consider inet_ntoa being the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're using IPv4. This function does NOT work with IPv6; use `inet_ntop()` or `inet_pton()` for IPv6.

The function returns a pointer to a *static internal* buffer that `inet_ntoa()` keeps re-using. Your `src_addr` and `dst_addr` will both point to the same buffer, and the string created by the LAST call to `inet_ntoa()` will be stored there.

Comment: Yeah, this is for an assignment involving local network traffic so I can safely assume it is IPv4 only.